# Как изменять цвет текста при использовании get set mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, get

Подскажите пожалуйста, как менять цвет текста, допустим число положительное цвет зеленый, а отрицательно цвет красный.

```
<Window x:Class="SampleSum.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleSum"
    xmlns:mvvm="clr-namespace:SampleSum.ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="150" Width="800">
<Window.DataContext>
    <mvvm:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid DataContext="{Binding SumModel}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Label Content="Первое число" Margin="0,2,0,32" Width="97" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding A, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0,2,0,31"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1">
        <Label Content="Второе число" Margin="0,2,0,32" Width="91" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding B, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="50" Height="28" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,7,0,0"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="2">
        <Label Content="Равно: " Margin="0,2,0,32" Width="58" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding C, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0,2,0,31"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Label Content="{Binding AllColor}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
</Grid>
```

```
public class SumModel : OnPropertyChangedClass
{
    int a = 5;
    int b;
    int c;
    public int A
    {
        get => a;
        set { a = value; OnAllPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    public int B
    {
        get => b;
        set { b = value; OnAllPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    public int C
    {
        get => AllSum();
        set { c = value; OnAllPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    public SumModel()
    {
        AllSum();
    }
    int AllSum()
    {
       return  c = a + b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможно дубликат: [Изменение значения прогрессбара в XAML с условный оператором](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/981982/218063)

Comment: Я так понимаю надо написать конвертер.

Comment: Да, по приведенной мною ссылке уже имеется готовый такой конвертер, вам остается только правильно написать триггеры

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое.